# Removing IE11 from windows search results

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

Trying to fully remove IE11 (and wordpad but I imagine any solution will be the same).

I have gone **into optional windows features and turned it off** but whilst I can no longer load it up, it annoying still shows when i search for it via the start menu.

This is my admittedly tiny issue but ideally I would like it to not show up at all.

I have tried rebuilding the search index and have checked that C:\Windows is in excluded folders **no luck**

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer is installed in `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer`.

When removing IE from Optional Features, not all files are removed, but the main IE executable is deleted. Presumably, some files are left behind so you can quickly reenable the IE feature.

I can't find a single forum that recommends removing the IE directories after disabling the feature, and don't want to potentially break my PC testing it. I would sandbox any further removals of files or directories related to IE in a Virtual Machine to test before deploying those changes to your main PC. You can download a Windows 10 ISO and start up a VirtualBox VM completely for free.

WordPad is located at `C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories` on Windows 10, and is uninstalled from the Windows 10 Settings > Apps & Features > Optional Features (this is not the same as the Windows Features control panel). Removing WordPad from Optional Features deletes the wordpad executable from the aforementioned directory.

[image: Optional Features, Remove Wordpad]

Comment: Sadly the UWP settings removal didnt work. I don't want to start manually deleting files which would more than likely break my install. Thanks you anyway.

Comment: https://d-manicx100.tinytake.com/media/dc4456?filename=1597912218801_TinyTake20-08-2020-09-30-01_637335090172269084.png&sub_type=thumbnail_preview&type=attachment&width=1200&height=554

Comment: I think you need to remove IE11 from the Control Panel Windows Features page. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGi1Z.png . I only said to remove WordPad in the UWP Optional Features. You could also exclude C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ from search. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GotyG.png